# mysql php access three rows without while loop

Tags: php, mysql, rows

This query always results in three rows.

```
$Z   = $myquery->execute($v); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($Z);
```

i dont want to do a while loop.. how can i just access as variables.

e.g.

```
 $row1 = the 1st column of row1
 $row2 = the 1st column of row1
 $row3 = the 1st column of row1
```

I thought something like this would work?

```
$row1 = $row[0][0];
```

Thanks.

Comment: you mean this $row1 = the 1st column of row1
 $row2 = the 1st column of row2
 $row3 = the 1st column of row3

Comment: The mysql extension doesn't have an OO interface, and doesn't have any function with `execute` in the name. Are you using mysqli?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that says a fetch function can only be called in a loop condition. At a language level, about the only thing that limits what function can be called in a given context is a [typehint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) on an argument to another function, and that limitation is on the type of an expression, not on the expression itself. Generally, if a function can be called in a given context, then any function can be called in that context.

mysqli:

```
$query = $db->prepare('...');
$query->bind_param(...);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$rows[] = $result->fetch_array();
$rows[] = $result->fetch_array();
$rows[] = $result->fetch_array();
```

PDO:

```
$query = $db->prepare('...');
$query->execute(...);
$row[] = $query->fetch();
$row[] = $query->fetch();
$row[] = $query->fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row();
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row();
$row3 = mysql_fetch_row();
```